# Rexgex : How to catch anything between parenthesis except when its between square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, brackets

I need a Regex to catch anything between parenthesis except when it is between the following pattern, an `S` char followed by square brackets:

```
S[]
```

Like in this sentence:

```
I am a (test) S[ but i am (not catched)], catch (me (if you can))
       ^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   # should be matched
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                            # should not be matched
```

It should also catch the nested parenthesis.

I tried to make it work using various example but the closest I get was this one :

```
(?![^S\[]*\])\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\([^()]*\))*\))*\))*\)?
```

=> but it fails when you remove the `S` from the test sentence.

Any idea of how to do it?

**Edit**: Should match like in this case but whith the S into account : https://regex101.com/r/WzECSS/1

**Edit**: this one should do the trick : `(?<!S\[[^\]]+)\((?:[^()]|\([^)]*\))+\)` thanks @ctwheels

**Edit**: the previous regex fails when you put the parenthesis directly after the square brackets like in:

"I am a (test) S[**(** but i am (not catched)], catch (me (if you can))"

Has anyone an idea on how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Please specify the expected result for your example.

Comment: can't you just do a two pass? ```replace(/S\[^]+\]/g,'')``` then capture your matching parenthesis?

Comment: If you make it a boolean like `S\[.*?\]|(\(.*?\))` then your desired results will be in `$1`. If you need to remove the `S` from the input then either make the `S` optional in the regex like this `S?\[.*?\]|(\(.*?\))` or remove it from the regex.

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/DiiYMT/1): `(?<=(?<!S)\[[^\]]*)\([^)]+\)(?=[^[]*\])|(?<=\([^)]*)\([^)]+\)(?=[^(]*\))` - requires ECMA2018+ for variable lookbehinds.

Comment: @KoshVery It should catch like in this example : https://regex101.com/r/sX5hZ2/1 , except that here it doesn't take the "S" into account. MonkeyZeus:  It should not match anything between S[ ... ], it does in what you provide. EDIT: sorry wrong link here is the good one => https://regex101.com/r/WzECSS/1

Comment: @ctwheels it doesn't work it only matches the *(if you can)* part look at this one : https://regex101.com/r/WzECSS/1

Comment: @xenope but you stated `catch anything between parenthesis except when it is between the following pattern [...] S[]`. What else is it supposed to match?

Comment: @ctwheels any parenthesis between S[ ...] must be ignored anything between the other parenthesis must be retrieved like here : https://regex101.com/r/WzECSS/1 **(test)** and **(me (if you can))** are matched

Comment: @xenope is my update to your question correct?

Comment: yes it is, any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Try `(?<!S\[[^\]]+)\((?:[^()]|\([^)]*\))+\)`

Comment: Dude you killed it! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex in ECMA2018+ (V8 engine or greater). Previous versions don't support variable length lookbehinds.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/DiiYMT/2)

```
(?<!S\[[^\]]+)\((?:[^()]|\([^)]*\))+\)
```

How this works:

- `(?<!S\[[^\]]+)` negative lookbehind ensuring the following does not match:

  - `S\[` match `S[` literally
  - `[^\]]+` match any character except `]` one or more times
- `\(` match `(` literally
- `(?:[^()]|\([^)]*\))+` match either of the following options one or more times

  - `[^()]` match any character except `(` and `)`
  - `\([^)]*\)` match `(`, then any character except `)` any number of times, then `)`
- `\)` match `)` literally

---

Please note, however, that this only matches to a depth of two parentheses (one set with another nested). You can't *easily* balance parentheses in JavaScript's regex engine since recursion and other tags aren't currently supported.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35271017/3600709) explains how to balance parentheses in different regex engines (including JavaScript if you use XRegExp).

Some examples of implementation in other languages - not possible in JavaScript since it doesn't include recursion, control verbs, balance groups, etc.:

**PCRE**: [See here](https://regex101.com/r/DiiYMT/3)

```
S\[[^]]*\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\((?:[^()]|(?R))*\)
```

**.NET**: [See here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!S%5C%5B%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D%2B%29%5C%28%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%28%29%5D%7C%28%3F%3Cp%3E%5C%28%29%7C%28%3F%3C-p%3E%5C%29%29%29%2B%28%3F%28p%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29&i=I%20am%20a%20%28test%29%20S%5B%20but%20i%20am%20%28not%20catched%29%5D%2C%20catch%20%28me%20%28if%20you%20%28%28%29%28%28%29%29%29%20can%29%29)

```
(?<!S\[[^\]]+)\((?:[^()]|(?<p>\()|(?<-p>\)))+(?(p)(?!))\)
```

---

### EDIT

Changing the quantifier in the lookbehind `+` to `*` prevents it from matching the case of `S[(...)]`:

```
(?<!S\[[^\]]*)\((?:[^()]|\([^)]*\))+\)
```

Comment: ++Very nice solution!

Comment: Fails with this use case : "I am a (test) S[( but i am (not catched)], catch (me (if you can))"

Comment: Any idea? @ctwheels maybe?

Comment: @xenope according to your question, it should not match `S[...]` - are you looking instead for it to not match `S[...]` unless it has a nested parentheses set `S[(())]`? If you are trying to match the nested parentheses sets within `S[]`, are you also looking to match the `S[]` part or just the nested parentheses set portion: `S[(a(b))]` or just `(a(b))` in that example?

Comment: @ctwheels Hi, It should never match the S[...] whatever is inside it, in this case if we put a parenthesis right after the brackets it matches it but I don't want to.